# My pipeline triggers twice, but it is set to trigger once a day

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have simple pipeline with copy activity that copies tables from on-premise to azure data warehouse and i have schedules trigger that should run once a day. But last 3-4 days it is triggered twice the same time both. One thing that has been changed last time, is Azure DevOps Git usage, we uploaded data factory to it by arm template. And now our project is in 'Data Factory' and also 'Azure DevOps Git'. But in Azure DevOps Git there are no pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i have found solution, in the left bottom corner of the data factory, in triggers menu you can edit trigger, and there is number of pipelines, and somehow my pipeline was mentioned there twice.